# Add a element to a PHP associative array

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

```
1=>america,2=>India,3=>england
```

Above is my associative array. How can I bring 3=>england to front of the array?

Comment: As the variety of answers show, there's more than one way to do this specific case.  It would help to know what you are actually trying to achieve - do you want the one with the highest numerical index at the front or do you just move the last element to the front or do you want '3 => england' to the front wherever it is in the array?  Or something else entirely?

Comment: This is not an associative array it's an indexed array, although in paractice, PHP imlpements indexed arrays as associative.

Comment: This question is ambiguous about whether the original keys need to be preserved or if the array keys should be re-assigned starting from 1.

Answer (score 3):

Use [array_pop](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-pop.php) and [array_unshift](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unshift.php).

```
$lastItem = array_pop($array);
array_unshift($array, $lastItem);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `array_unshift` function for that.

```
$array = array('americ', 'India');
array_unshift($array, 'englans');
print_r($array);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => englans
    [1] => americ
    [2] => India
)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to preserve the array keys use `array_slice(,,,TRUE)`.

```
$array = array_slice( $array, -1, 1, TRUE ) + array_slice( $array, 0, -1, TRUE );
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$temp = myArray[3];
$myArray[3] = $myArray[2];
$myArray[2] = $myArray[1];
$myArray[1] = $temp;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with `array_reverse`, docs you can find at http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php

Answer (score 1):

```
krsort($myArray, SORT_NUMERIC)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`array_pop`](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.array-pop.php) and [`array_unshift`](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unshift.php) for this:

```
$last = array_pop($array);
array_unshift($array, $last);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think he wants to have element 3=>england to the front so he can use it with foreach and the rest of the array has to stay on the same place

than he wants this result

```
$array[1] = 'america';
$array[2] = 'India';
$array[3] = 'england';
$new_array[3] = $array[3];
$new_array[1] = $array[1];
$new_array[2] = $array[2];
print_r($new_array);
```

there is probably a function for but i cant find it so i made one

```
function placeLastToFirst($array){
    $newArray = array();
    $newArray[count($array)] = $array[count($array)];
    for($i = 1;$i < count($array);$i++){

        $newArray[$i] = $array[$i ];
    }
    return $newArray;
}
```

you have to look out because this function will only work if the array begins with 1 (normal arrays begin with 0). In that case you can use this one

```
function placeLastToFirst($array){
    $newArray = array();
    $newArray[count($array)-1] = $array[count($array)-1];
    for($i = 0;$i < count($array)-1;$i++){

        $newArray[$i] = $array[$i];
    }
    return $newArray;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$contractTypes = array('' => 'All') + $contractTypes;
```